# How to pass a file to an API call through WordPress

Tags: php, api

I want to pass a file to an API call for translation the action of this button of submit still doesn't direct to any page, so should I make this pure PHP or Ajax gonna take a role here?

[image]

This's the PHP code that takes the file as a parameter for the API and should return another translated file or maybe translated text.

```
 $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.matecat.com/api/v1/new');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    $post = array(
        'files' => '@' . realpath('Request For Proposal - API Integration Of Hubspot.com and SMRT Systems.pdf;type=application/pdf'),
        'project_name' => 'firsttest',
        'source_lang' => 'en-US',
        'target_lang' => 'es-ES',
        'tms_engine' => '1',
        'mt_engine' => '1',
        'private_tm_key' => 'ssssadsads',
        'subject' => 'general',
        'owner_email' => 'anonymous',
        'get_public_matches' => 'true'
    );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Accept: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I think you'll have to do at least part of this in the backend, else you'll need to put your matecat API key in JavaScript where anyone can find it. You can do this as a WordPress REST API endpoint though, or an old-style admin-ajax call.

Comment: What specifically is the problem at this point - acting on the form submission? Where are you submitting the form to - back to the current page? What code have you written to handle this? i.e. the bit before your curl sequence.

Comment: I'm thinking of creating a custom Ajax in Wordpress and return the File from Ajax to the back-end function, the submission maybe I'm gonna create another file that handles the uploading on the theme but I can't identify which part of the theme I should add my code at.

Comment: I'm trying also to edit the theme on VS code and then re-upload it I get this error `Unpacking the package…

Installing the theme…

The package could not be installed. The style.css stylesheet does not contain a valid theme header.

Theme installation failed.` 

when I added valid header to the Css file didn't work either